# .loc only returning first value in a list instead of the full list

Tags: pandas, pandas-loc

I have a data frame and I'm trying to return all the matching values in one column based on another column using loc.  The dataframe looks like this.

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Alpha | Bravo |
| Alpha | Charlie |
| Delta | Charlie |
| Delta | Echo |
| Delta | Echo |
| Mike | Rodeo |

I'm wanting to return an additional column that has all the values in Col2 for each item in Col1.  I tried posting the second table, but StackOverflow thought it was a code command and won't let me post.

When I run this code, Col3 is value from Col2 and not the full list, but when I run only the right side of the code for a specific value, it returns the correct list

```
for value in col1_values:
    df.loc[df['Col1'].eq(value),'Col3'] = list(df['Col2'].loc[df['Col1'].eq(value)])
```

Comment: `df.groupby("Col1")["Col2"].agg(list)` kind of thing?

Comment: Yep, that's it exactly.